# Creating histogram in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index with several documents. A field found in each document is "id". I want to know how many documents per id count. There can be several documents for each id. Just like in any store there can be many transactions for each customer, for instance.

Meaning for instance, I want to get something like: "There are 5 ids with 1 document. There are 10 ids with 2 documents" and so on.

How can I write that aggregation in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Basically a single document can have multiple values in its `id` field. And the expectations is to return how many documents have single ids or 2 ids or 3 ids in their `id` field. For e.g response should be like id:1 and value should be total documents having singular value in id. Correct?

Comment: No. Each document only has one value in its id field, but there can be several (different!) documents with the same id. Think of document as store item and id as client that bought the item. We both bought a can of coca cola, but the cans have different ids because you and i have different ids. What I want to know is how many different customers bought 1 item. How many different customers bought 2 items etc. Imagine instead of id, I said "client_id". Each document has one client_id, but there can be several different documents with the same client_id

Answer (score -1):

I believe this would be a classic [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Something along these lines should work for you:

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "ids" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "id" } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me "For each id, how many documents  have that id". This gives me "id 123 has 5 documents" etc. What I want is "250 different ids have 1 document. 500 different ids have 2 documents" etc. Not exactly what you wrote.

Comment: I tried to look for a solution by combining the above terms aggregation with a cardinality or pipeline aggregation, but even using the scripts I have not found a way to do this. Maybe there's a different, easier approach, but I have not found it. The terms aggregation provides all the information that is needed for you, so if you are able to do so, I would probably group the information the way you want in the frontend. Of course if that's not possible,  it might be possible to do what you want with scripting, but I couldn't find one.